# Duplicating items already in array

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

Every time I run the app, and then re-run it, it saves the same items into the `NSUserDefaults` even if it is already there.

I tried to fix that with `contains` code, but it hasn't worked.

What am I missing?

```
    for days in results! {
        let nD = DayClass()
        nD.dayOfTheWeek = days[“D”] as! String
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if var existingArr = defaults.arrayForKey("D") as? [String] {
                if existingArr.contains(days["D"] as! String) == false {
                    existingArr.append(nd.dayOfTheWeek)
                }
            } else {
                defaults.setObject([nD.dayOfTheWeek], forKey: "D")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give some more information of what you are try to do with the array.

Comment: Victor, you shouldn't use defaults.synchronize(). "So yeah, long story short, do not use synchronize in iOS 8 and later." -http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/ Also you should try only defining defaults (let defaults =...) once, at the top of your project.

Comment: @JohnRamos ok thanks!  I changed that, and it is still doing the same thing. But maybe you were more looking at formatting tips, etc. which thanks.

Comment: @Cing I'm pulling "days of the week" from an API for example.  It happens to pull Monday, puts it in the array.  Then when I run the app a second time, it pulls Monday again, and puts it in the array again; where what I would want is to see if Monday is already in the array to not put it in there again.  Make sense at all?  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnRamos I updated my formatting and code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every time I run the app, and then re-run it, it saves the same items into the NSUserDefaults even if it is already there.

Yes, because that's exactly what your code does:

```
defaults.setObject(existingArr, forKey: "D")
```

But what is `existingArr`? It's the defaults you've just loaded before:

```
if var existingArr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("D") as? [String]
```

So what happens is that when you enter the `.contains` branch, you always do the same operation: you save the existing array.

Contrary to what your comment in the code states, you're not appending anything to any array in that block, you're saving the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was thinking `if var existingArr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("D")` would set up an array of the items I have in defaults, then `if existingArr.contains(nD.dayOfTheWeek) == false {` would check to see if I already have that day of the week in there and if not then it would add it. So is what you are saying that `defaults.setObject(existingArr, forKey: "D")` is the code that is wrong, then I updated my code to `append` to the existing array if that is what you are saying? Hope it is clearer now.  Thanks!